# Open Source tools similar to Security Monkey for Azure?

Tags: open-source, security

Recently implemented Security Monkey on an assignment; and now have a new challenge with Azure.

Does anyone know of any similar (must be open source) tools; that can be used for policy validations; checking inbound security groups, users not using MFA etc.?

Looked around but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Try OpenSCAP https://www.open-scap.org/ your question is rather broad. E.g.: "Anyone not using MFA..." for me means those users will never gain access by secure design. Seems like you're trying to solve a design problem with a tool. In any event try OpenSCAP

Comment: Thanks. This is the tool we went with in the end.